# How to convert numeric values to time without the date?

Tags: r

I want convert numeric values to time without the date for the data like `1215,1423,1544,1100,0645,1324` in R. 
These data has to read like `12:15,14:23,15:44`.
I was trying `as.POSIXct`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strptime` with `format`

```
format(strptime(sprintf("%04d", v1), "%H%M"), "%H:%M")
```

---

The above output is `character` class, but if we needed a `times` class, then we can use `times` from `chron` on a "HH:MM:SS" format created with `sub` or from the above code

```
library(chron)
times(sub("(.{2})(.{2})","\\1:\\2:", sprintf("%04d00", v1)))
#[1] 12:15:00 14:23:00 15:44:00 11:00:00 06:45:00 13:24:00
```

Or

```
times(format(strptime(sprintf("%04d", v1), "%H%M"), "%H:%M:%S"))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( 1215,1423,1544,1100,0645,1324)
```